# Accordion panel misbehaves

Tags: jsf, primefaces

hello stackoverflow,

i am beginner to primefaces . and I have a question . this is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>facelets</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:accordionPanel style="width:300px;" > 
            <p:tab title="tab1">
                <h:commandLink value="click"></h:commandLink>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink value="next"></h:commandLink>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink value="previous"></h:commandLink>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="tab2" id="panel">
                <p:commandLink value="click" action="override" update="panel"></p:commandLink>

                <br />
                <p:commandLink value="next" action="header"></p:commandLink>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink value="previous"></h:commandLink>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="tab3">
                <h:commandLink value="click"></h:commandLink>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink value="next"></h:commandLink>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink value="previous"></h:commandLink>

            </p:tab>

        </p:accordionPanel>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

whenver i click the commandlinks present in the second or third tabs , after selection it navigates to the first tab , and its not staying in the tab where i performed the selection Say if i clicked the "click" link inside the juniper tab , then it navigates to the first tab. any suggestions are always welcome . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use partialsubmit="true" in your commandlink.
The reason for the Accordian to reset itself is that once you click on any commandlink the whole form is being refreshed instead of the panel itself. Partial submit will do a partial refresh.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1842

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but it didnt work i tried .

Comment: What is the action of these commandlinks? is it invoking any mbeans or something?

Comment: it invokes another .xhtml page . (It uses the same above page as template using facelets)

Comment: Ok. Whether are you able to get on to the other .xhtml page ? Or it is just staying on the current page.? Sorry for asking so many questions but I need to know what is the expected behavior and actual result you are getting.

Comment: no probs dude . As in the above code , say if i click the link , which is present in the second tab , it opens it , but instead of staying in the second tab it oves to the first tab . (FYI , i have used the same above page as template in the currently opened page )

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Did you try setting dynamic="true" cache="false" in you accordian panel. I dont have the resource to test it but I think you can give it a shot. Let me know.

Comment: same result dude , again the first tab opens . do you know that , should i need to use activeindex or something ?

Comment: You can very well set the ActiveIndex but then you need to go via your mbean method.